# array in std::tuple passed to std::tuple_cat in decltype error - g++ vs clang++ - which compiler is right

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, language-lawyer, clang++

Consider the code below:

```
#include <tuple>

int main() {
   std::tuple<char[2], int> t1;
   std::tuple<int> t2;
   decltype(std::tuple_cat(t1, t2)) t3;
}
```

It compiles fine with `g++` (in version >= 5.2) and `icc` (13.0.1), but not in `clang++` and older versions of `g++` where it gives nasty error:

> array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal

My hunch tells me that the code shouldn't compile and `clang++` and older versions of `g++` are actually right here, but want to take a second opinion.

Comment: You broke a [*Requires*](http://eel.is/c++draft/tuple#tuple.creation-10) clause, so it's UB. Both are right.

Comment: Compiles in MSVC 2015 too

Comment: @T.C. Looks like it's worth an answer.

Comment: I get the error even with `std::tuple<char[2]> t1;`

Comment: @T.C. Yep this is definitly it. But shoudn't compiler be more deterministic here? It compiles only when you put `std::tuple_cat(t1, t2)` inside `decltype` clause...

Comment: even simpler: error with `#include <tuple> int main() { std::tuple<char[2]> t1; decltype(std::tuple_cat(t1)) t2; }`

Comment: @max66 what compiler are you using?

Comment: @Wojciech Frohmberg - yes; error with `-std=c++11` and with `-std=c++14`; with clang++ 3.5 and with g++ 4.9.2

Comment: @max66 Yes, as I said it compiles with `g++` since version `5.2`