# Are there any reasons why c++ template packs are passed using std::tuple

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++14, variadic-templates

Let's say we want to create a helper class to reverse template pack e.g. as follows:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

template <class>
struct sizer;

template <template<class...> class Pack, class... Args>
struct sizer<Pack<Args...>> {
   static constexpr size_t value = sizeof...(Args);
};

template <class Pack, class Indices = std::make_index_sequence<sizer<Pack>::value>>
struct reverse_pack;

template <class... Args, size_t... I>
struct reverse_pack<std::tuple<Args...>, std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, I...>> {
    using type = typename std::tuple<typename std::tuple_element<(sizeof...(Args) - I - 1), std::tuple<Args...>>::type...>;
};

int main() {
   std::cout << typeid(reverse_pack<std::tuple<int, float, double>>::type).name() << std::endl;
}
```

We could successfully do exactly the same thing using e.g. function signature as a template parameter:

```
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

template <class>
struct sizer;

template <class... Args>
struct sizer<void(Args...)> {
   static constexpr size_t value = sizeof...(Args);
};

template <size_t N, class Sign>
struct nth_param;

template <size_t N, class First, class... Args>
struct nth_param<N, void(First, Args...)>: nth_param<N-1, void(Args...)> { };

template <class First, class... Args>
struct nth_param<0, void(First, Args...)> {
   using type = First;
};

template <class Pack, class Indices = std::make_index_sequence<sizer<Pack>::value>>
struct reverse_pack;

template <class... Args, size_t... I>
struct reverse_pack<void(Args...), std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, I...>> {
    using type = void(typename nth_param<(sizeof...(Args) - I - 1), void(Args...)>::type...);
};

int main() {
   std::cout << typeid(reverse_pack<void(int, float, double)>::type).name() << std::endl;
}
```

My experience with `std::tuple` (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421194/array-in-stdtuple-passed-to-stdtuple-cat-in-decltype-error-g-vs-clang)) shows its intended to store data rather than to pass packs of types between template. So are there any practical reasons to use a tuple to operate on variadics?

Comment: A glance at the two code samples shows reduced length because `tuple_element` doesn't have to be recreated.

Comment: A function parameter type may not be an array, whereas a tuple element type may be.

Comment: A function signature is a wrong choice. It adjusts its parameters, e.g. a function is adjusted to a function pointer, constness is dropped etc.

Comment: What else would you use? `struct`, `class` and `union` do not allow you to check which and how many types are inside. You can use a `pair` sometimes, but that is really a specialized `tuple`.

Comment: Developers tend to use `std::tuple` because it comes with facilities such as `tuple_element` out of the box.

Comment: @KerrekSB yes it's a good argument against function signature

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So are there any practical reasons to use a `tuple` to operate on variadics?

A `tuple` doesn't perform any conversions on its arguments - a `tuple<int[2]>` indeed contains an `int[2]` as its first type, whereas a `void(int[2])` is really a `void(int*)`. The same holds for `const`, functions, and other types that undergo decay. That makes function a non-viable option.

If you wrote your own typelist (e.g. `template <class... Ts> struct typelist{};`), you would still have to reimplement  `std::get`, `std::tuple_element`, and `std::tuple_size`. That's the nice thing about `tuple` - it comes ready and useful.

And everybody already knows what `std::tuple` is. Even if function signatures didn't decay their arguments in a way that would break, I would still use the type that's created to be a heterogeneous container of types - and not shoehorn your solution into something else that happens to work. Principle of least surprise and all.

Comment: The downsides are large however: `std::tuple` is pretty heavy weight, and creating dozens or 100s of instances of it can really bog down compile time.

Comment: @Yakk Hopefully the language/library will advance to the point where `std::tuple` isn't so heavyweight.

Comment: Is it possible to store an array in a tuple with `tuple<int[2]>`? I thought you need `std::array<>` for that. Can you please explain?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yeah, you can.

Comment: @Barry this does not compile http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c4bd67e692952c6

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Yeah, you can't initialize it like that, and you can't copy/move it - so it's of limited use. But you can use it in local scope. I think this is again ultimately the problem of `tuple` not actually being an aggregate.

Comment: @Barry so I understand it as you are saying that you can default-construct a tuple that contains an array and can perhaps `get<..>` the array by reference. Is this blessed by the spec?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I don't see anything that would disallow it.

Comment: There are still types that `tuple` doesn't play well with, though.