# What's the use of `std::tuple<int[N]>`?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

Here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37550660/34509) user [@Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37550660/34509) notes in the comment section that you can use `std::tuple<int[2]>` and that it is not apparently forbidden to instantiate such a type. I have not yet heard about this beast and I wonder what uses it could have, as opposed to storing a `int var[2]` directly or using `std::array<int, 2>`.

Reportedly, `std::tuple<int[2]>` is not copyable, neither movable nor construtable from an `int var[2]`. What other uses does it have?

Comment: It's a great way to represent a type list with one element that is `int[2]`.

Comment: Is it a personal question to Barry? :) On a less joking mode, I would assume, it has it's use when the actual number of arguments to tuple is unknown, and a single array is a particular case?

Comment: @SergeyA it is a question to the community, perhaps there is a good rationale for allowing this?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, allowing or using? It is allowed because it falls under general rule. There is nothing to prohibit it. But using it is another question.

Comment: When does a `std::tuple<X>` not be better replaced with an `X`?  The question about why not `int var[2]` seems a poor one that distracts from the rest of your question, no?

Comment: @FirstStep your question is a bit ambiguous. Do you mean me to give an example of how to get my SO score, or an example declaration of a `tuple<int[2]> x;`?

Comment: @johannes nah I stated that "MCVE just _with me_" means on my question ))

Comment: @Yakk: For X some use cases come to mind e.g. wrapping an error prone type (e.g. void* or sth. alike) into some robust shell. For int[2] I have no idea, since std::array actually does exactly this and more for x[n]

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure this is undefined behavior. See the *Requires* and *Returns* clause:

[tuple.creation-10 and 12](http://eel.is/c++draft/tuple#tuple.creation-10) says:

> *Requires:* For all *i*, *U<sub>i</sub>* shall be the type *cv<sub>i</sub>* `tuple<Argsi...>`, where
>   *cv<sub>i</sub>* is the (possibly empty) *<sup>i</sup>th* cv-qualifier-seq and *Args<sub>i</sub>* is the parameter pack
>   representing the element types in *U<sub>i</sub>*. Let
>   *A<sub>ik</sub>* be the *k<sub>i</sub><sup>th</sup>* type in *Args<sub>i</sub>*. For all *A<sub>ik</sub>* the following requirements shall be satisfied: If *T<sub>i</sub>* is deduced as an
>   lvalue reference type, then `is_constructible<Aik, cvi Aik&>::value == true`, otherwise `is_constructible<Aik, cvi Aik&&>::value == true`.
>
> *Returns:* A `tuple` object constructed by initializing the *k<sub>i</sub><sup>th</sup>* type element *e<sub>ik</sub>* in *e<sub>i</sub>...* with `get<ki>(std::forward<Ti>(tpi))`
>   for each valid *k<sub>i</sub>* and each group *e<sub>i</sub>* in
>   order.

Like Barry says, there's nothing preventing `std::tuple<int[2]> t;` but trying to do anything with it is likely to cause a hard error in a compiler. Example:

```
std::tuple<int[2]> t; // fine
std::tuple<int[2]> t{}; // fine
```

While:

```
std::tuple<int[2]> a() {
  int a[2] = { 1, 2};
  return std::tuple<int[2]>(a);
}

int main() {
   auto x = a();
   // ...
}
```

gives errors like:

```
error: array initializer must be an initializer list
        : _M_head_impl(std::forward<_UHead>(__h)) { }
```

Comment: That requires clause only applies to `tuple_cat`.

Comment: It's amazing the effort people go through to format standardese without fact checking.